# Is there a Keycloak API to get Users under Client Role?

Tags: keycloak-services

Hi I'm using Keycloak and I would like to know what is the best way to get Users in Client Role. Is there a Keycloak API to get this?

I can get user role details with jwt token. But I need to get all users under a client role

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with English. Thank you for your understanding.

## Grant the client role to a user

#### Get representation of the client

```
## If you know the uid of the client, you don't need it.
## If you don't know the client's uid, you can get it with this.
GET /{realm}/clients?clientId={client-name}
```

#### Get a role by name

```
GET /{realm}/clients/{client-uid}/roles/{role-name}
```

#### Get all roles for the realm or client

```
GET /{realm}/clients/{client-uid}/roles
```

#### Get a role by name

```
GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}
```

```py
# python example
url = "{}/auth/admin/realms/{}/clients/{}/roles?".format(kc_url, kc_realm, client_uid)
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'bearer {}'.format(token)
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
```

#### Add client-level roles to the user role mapping

```
## Add the information you got from the role name to the body.
POST /{realm}/users/{id}/role-mappings/clients/{client-uid}
```

```py
# python example
url = "{}/auth/admin/realms/{}/users/{}/role-mappings/clients/{}".format(kc_url, kc_realm, user_uid, client_uid)

list = []
list.append(role_info)

payload = json.dumps(list)

headers = {
    'Authorization': 'bearer {}'.format(token),
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

## Get a list of users who have been granted the client role

#### Returns a stream of users that have the specified role name.

```
GET /{realm}/clients/{id}/roles/{role-name}/users
```

See the [documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/15.0/rest-api/index.html) for more APIs.
You can also grant a client role when creating a user.
Adding the client role to the group and adding the user to the group is also a way.

Comment: Thank you for your help! we will check your suggestions